# Please suggest an e-book for anti design pattern?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I would like to know "anti-design". Please suggest an e-book for anti design pattern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may like to check out:
[**The daily wtf**](http://thedailywtf.com/Default.aspx) & [**Anti patterns**](http://www.antipatterns.com/AntiPatterns/Welcome.html)

Comment: Love the daily wtf. Very humorous.

Answer (score 2):

Not an e-book, but the only book I know: “[AntiPatterns: Refactoring Software, Architectures, and Projects in Crisis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AntiPatterns)” (the link is to Wikipedia's book review).

For some reason I always thought that book was by Martin Fowler, but it wasn’t.

Wikipedia also has an incomplete list of [common antipatterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern).

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 1):

I have seen books on refactoring.
But I don't think I have ever seen a book on presenting bad code.

The closest thing you can find that shows examples of bad code is in Code Complete by Steven McConnel. The author puts in these little snippets called "Coding Horror" that are examples of bad code. He then explains how to write good code instead, in those situations.

This book is simply the best book on good coding practices I have ever seen.

Answer (score 1):

You may find the articles from [SourceMaking](http://sourcemaking.com/antipatterns) interesting.